# How do I implement `fprintd` into login in Kubuntu?

Tags: kde, login, kubuntu, fingerprint

I have set up `fprintd` and added a fingerprint profile, but now I am stuck: how do I get this to let me log in? I have added

```
auth sufficient pam_unix.so try_first_pass likeauth nullok
auth sufficient pam_fprintd.so
```

at the beginning of `/etc/pam.d/sddm` as suggested [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/SDDM#Using_a_fingerprint_reader) which did not change anything (I did use a tab between `auth` and `sufficient`, and `sufficient` and `pam_...` instead of spaces, but this seems more consistent with the other entries in the file. I did use spaces between `pam_unix.so`, `try_first_pass`, `likeauth` and `nullok`. Could this affect anything?). I have added them so that they are the first line of code in the file. The page also says

> To make it work in KDE's lock screen, also add the same line at the beginning of `/etc/pam.d/kde`

but I have no such file! I was directed to that wiki entry from [this one](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Fprint#Configuration), but I *also* don't have an `/etc/pam.d/system-local-login` file, and my attempts to add the code to the `sudo` file to test the waters have not worked so far. I think I might be adding the line in the wrong place in the file, or using spaces where I should use tabs. Does this sound plausible? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer myself! [Here it is](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237451/using-fingerprint-reader-in-kubuntu-20-04-on-thinkpad-t495). In case that link goes dead, here is the text:

Install the applications needed:

```
sudo apt install -y fprintd libpam-fprintd
sudo pam-auth-update
```

Once install finishes, open /etc/pam.d/common-auth for editing

```
$ sudoedit /etc/pam.d/common-auth
auth [success=1 default=ignore] pam_unix.so nullok_secure
```

And modify the file adding the line shown below in bold. Make sure the order of these lines is the same as shown here.

```
auth [success=2 default=ignore] pam_fprintd.so max_tries=1 timeout=10 
auth [success=1 default=ignore] pam_unix.so nullok_secure
```

Save.

Finally, enroll your fingerprint with the following command:

`fprintd-enroll $USER`

After running the command, swipe your finger across the reader 3 times to enroll your fingerprint.

But! Login screen works uncorrected.

Comment: Just be wary, I could no longer login at the login screen after this change.